# Adding to Word document with bullet formatting at end

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I work on a process that reads a Word document and appends some images to the end of it. The issue I'm running into is that the document ends with a lettered list and the images I am appending are becoming a part of that list. I can't seem to find a way to end that list before adding the images.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword =
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
winword.Visible = false;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Open(documentName);

object lastLine = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
object lastDirection = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
document.Sections.Add(missing);
document.Sections[document.Sections.Count]
    .Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].LinkToPrevious = false;
document.Sections[document.Sections.Count]
    .Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text = "";

winword.Selection.GoTo(ref lastLine, ref lastDirection, ref missing, ref missing);
winword.Selection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory, missing);

foreach(string image in images)
{
    document.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(image);
}

document.SaveAs2("finished.doc",
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97);
document.Close();
winword.Quit();
```

Comment: so after toying with this some more, I noticed that the 
`document.Sections.Add(missing);`
was actually adding into the list that precedes it in the document that I have opened. I still cant figure out how to get outside of the list with the items I am adding.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? I believe it's a matter of applying Normal style and removing direct formatting, but it would help if to find out exactly what's in that document. Also, your code could be a lot more efficient...